# How to check if a series of dates are coherent in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Let's say I have this example df (but with so many dates) :

```
library(lubridate)

df = data.frame(id = 1:5,
                date1 = dmy(c('01/02/2021','03/05/2022','01/03/2021','08/12/2021','01/02/2021')),
                date2 = dmy(c('03/02/2021','04/06/2022','03/08/2021','08/11/2022','02/05/2021')),
                date3 = dmy(c('04/03/2021','03/08/2022','06/09/2021','09/08/2022','03/06/2021')),
                date4 = dmy(c('05/08/2021','08/09/2022','09/10/2021','21/12/2022','03/07/2021')),
                date5 = dmy(c('09/11/2021','11/08/2022','04/11/2021','10/02/2023','04/11/2021')))
```

I want a simple way to check that all the dates are coherent for each id (that date1<date2 and date1<date3 and date2 < date3 and so on ...). Meaning that I want to check if there are no mistakes for each two dates including all possibilities.

Update : second scenario :

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:5,
                date1 = dmy(c('01/02/2021','03/05/2022','01/03/2021','08/12/2021','01/02/2021')),
                date2 = dmy(c('03/02/2021','04/06/2022','03/08/2021','08/11/2022','02/05/2021')),
                date3 = dmy(c('04/03/2021','03/08/2022',NA,'09/08/2022','03/06/2021')),
                date4 = dmy(c('05/08/2021','08/09/2022',NA,'21/12/2022','03/07/2021')),
                date5 = dmy(c('09/11/2021','11/08/2022','04/11/2021','10/02/2023','04/11/2021')))
```

When there are NA values and applying the function as mentioned, the output is :

```
 A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
     id date1      date2      date3      date4      date5      is_coherent
  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <lgl>      
1     1 2021-02-01 2021-02-03 2021-03-04 2021-08-05 2021-11-09 TRUE       
2     2 2022-05-03 2022-06-04 2022-08-03 2022-09-08 2022-08-11 FALSE      
3     3 2021-03-01 2021-08-03 NA         NA         2021-11-04 NA         
4     4 2021-12-08 2022-11-08 2022-08-09 2022-12-21 2023-02-10 FALSE      
5     5 2021-02-01 2021-05-02 2021-06-03 2021-07-03 2021-11-04 TRUE
```

How to tell R to ignore NAs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check for every possible combination of dates. If A < B and B < C then automatically A < C.

We can take difference of consecutive dates and return `TRUE` if the difference for all of them is greater than 0.

You may do this using base R `apply` :

```
df$is_coherent <- apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) all(diff(as.Date(x)) > 0))
df

#  id      date1      date2      date3      date4      date5 is_coherent
#1  1 2021-02-01 2021-02-03 2021-03-04 2021-08-05 2021-11-09        TRUE
#2  2 2022-05-03 2022-06-04 2022-08-03 2022-09-08 2022-08-11       FALSE
#3  3 2021-03-01 2021-08-03 2021-09-06 2021-10-09 2021-11-04        TRUE
#4  4 2021-12-08 2022-11-08 2022-08-09 2022-12-21 2023-02-10       FALSE
#5  5 2021-02-01 2021-05-02 2021-06-03 2021-07-03 2021-11-04        TRUE
```

Or implementing the same logic using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(is_coherent = all(diff(c_across(starts_with("date"))) > 0))
```

Comment: yes you are right thank you. And is there a way to know where the error is when it is not coherent ?

Comment: You may try `apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) which(diff(as.Date(x)) < 0) + 1)` to get the index where the dates are not coherent.

Comment: Please check another scenario of the same dataframe that I added to the question

Comment: Maybe :

`
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(is_coherent = {
    diffs <- diff(na.omit(c_across(starts_with("date"))))
    all(diffs > 0)
  })
`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(matrixStats::rowDiffs(sapply(df, as.numeric)) < 0) |> apply(1, which) |>
  setNames(df$id) |> unlist() |> names()
# [1] "2.date5" "4.date3"
```

which reads id "2": column "date5", and id "4": column "date3"

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, date1 = structure(c(18659, 19115, 18687, 
18969, 18659), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(18661, 19147, 
18842, 19304, 18749), class = "Date"), date3 = structure(c(18690, 
19207, 18876, 19213, 18781), class = "Date"), date4 = structure(c(18844, 
19243, 18909, 19347, 18811), class = "Date"), date5 = structure(c(18940, 
19215, 18935, 19398, 18935), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```